# PHPMyAdmin 4.9: Failed to set session cookie

Tags: ubuntu, php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I've installed PHPmyadmin 4.9 in ubuntu trusty with nginx and PHP7.1 installed. With PHP is using memcache as session handler. However when I configured phpmyadmin I always get the error

```
Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin.
```

I searched this and I know it is not related to cookies are I tried them. I saw the tmp folder inside phpmyadmin so I'm assuming that the sessions are create inside there not unless it is trying to use the memcache by default due to php fpm. Any Ideas ?

Comment: Please comment on https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15634 to have support on this issue :)